# json_query for a value of json output in Ansible

Tags: ansible

The following outputs to the shell when I run my Ansible play:

```
TASK [java : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.3.16.114] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "examined": 1,
        "failed": false,
        "files": [
            {
                "attributes": "Directory, NotContentIndexed",
                "creationtime": 1551375173.18858,
                "filename": "jre1.8.0_201",
                "isarchive": false,
                "isdir": true,
                "ishidden": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreadonly": false,
                "isshared": false,
                "lastaccesstime": 1551375199.2058175,
                "lastwritetime": 1551375199.2058175,
                "owner": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM",
                "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_201",
                "size": 205713652
            }
        ],
        "matched": 1
    }
}
```

I need just the value of `path` so that I can use it as a varuable to set a dynamic java_home inside of windows.

I have been trying to use `json_query` inside of my yaml but I'm having knowledge limitations here.

```
- name: Obtain information about a folder
  win_find:
    paths: C:\Program Files\Java
    recurse: no
    file_type: directory
  register: java_folder

- set_fact:
    java_home_dir: "{{java_folder.file | json_query()}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple path. Addressing of the first element is needed, because "*files*" is a list.

```
- set_fact:
    java_home_dir: "{{ java_folder.files[0].path }}"
```

If there is more files in the list json_query will be needed.